# Shape of array python

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I create a 2 dimensional array

```
 m = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(1000, 2))
 q = np.zeros(shape=(1000,1))
 print m[:,0] -q
```

When I take `m[:,0].shape` I get `(1000,)` as opposed to `(1000,1)` which is what I want. How do I coerce `m[:,0]` to a `(1000,1)` array?

Comment: I simply want a one column vector with 1000 rows as I am trying to subtract two column vectors

Comment: I think `(1000,)` is the same as `(1000,1)`

Comment: @MattDMo: they're sometimes interchangeable because of how numpy broadcasting works, but they're not quite the same thing.

Comment: You can see that if you just enter `m[:,0]` (prepare for a bit of scrolling, though :)

Comment: if I do m[:0,] - q I get a 1000x1000 matrix as opposed to a 1000X1 array. very annoying

Comment: @DSM I see. What specifically are the differences? I'm still not completely up to speed on all the ins and outs of broadcasting (only half way through "Python For Data Analysis", which is a great book BTW)

Comment: @MattDMo: well, the two objects have different dimensionality, for one.  For a good broadcasting explanation you can read [this](http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc) tutorial.

Comment: @lord12 - so, from DSM's answer and my own experimentation, `m[:,:1]` should work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By selecting the 0th column in particular, as you've noticed, you reduce the dimensionality:

```
>>> m = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(5, 2))
>>> m[:,0].shape
(5,)
```

You have a lot of options to get a 5x1 object back out.  You can index using a list, rather than an integer:

```
>>> m[:, [0]].shape
(5, 1)
```

You can ask for "all the columns up to but not including 1":

```
>>> m[:,:1].shape
(5, 1)
```

Or you can use `None` (or `np.newaxis`), which is a general trick to extend the dimensions:

```
>>> m[:,0,None].shape
(5, 1)
>>> m[:,0][:,None].shape
(5, 1)
>>> m[:,0, None, None].shape
(5, 1, 1)
```

Finally, you can reshape:

```
>>> m[:,0].reshape(5,1).shape
(5, 1)
```

but I'd use one of the other methods for a case like this.

Comment: Just to note, using `m[:,[0]]` is subtly different since it triggers fancy indexing, which means the result is not a view.

Comment: @seberg: true enough.  I'm fortunate in that I seldom have to worry, either on memory or performance fronts, and so I've probably grown a little sloppy..